# Umbraco 4.11 get Parent Node

Tags: c#, umbraco

Should be a simple answer.

I am using Umbraco 4.11 and I need to get the parent Node of a cast node.  I am a bit of a noob to C# and I am fixing a control someone else made.  Should be simple but it was originally written before the DLL update from 4.7 to 4.11.

So below is my code. I need to get the parent Node. What would be the correct syntax to do this.  You can see where the old code is commented out.

Thanks in advance.

```
 //New using
 using umbraco.NodeFactory;

 private string GetEmailContactProperty()
    {
        Node node = Node.GetCurrent();
        string email = null;

        do
        {
            if (node.NodeTypeAlias == NodeTypeAlias)
            {
                email = node.GetProperty("emailContact").Value;

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                    break;
            }

            //node = node.Parent;
           //***Need Parent Node here. new Node is asking for Overload.
            node = new Node().Parent;

        } while(node.Parent.Id > -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The original code should do what you are asking with regards to getting the parent node.

```
node = node.Parent;
```

Comment: The changed their Using so the base Umbraco call does not use node.Parent; anymore. I tried and got an error.

Comment: You don't say what the error was but most likely a null reference error when there is no parent.

Comment: That is the error we were getting. The issue is the using I had used to be umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory, changed to umbraco.NodeFactory. I put the .presentation.nodeFactory back in and you solution did not error in VS.  But Umbraco was giving a null reference. That is why I was bug hunting. I just went with a different solution. This form was overkill for our needs. +1 for you though for the most correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, from your code you want to traverse up the tree, across your ancestors, to find a property named "emailContact" that is not IsNullOrEmpty.

I think what you are looking for is a piece of code like this:

```
var emailContact = CurrentModel.AncestorsOrSelf().Items.Where(n => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(n.GetProperty("emailContact").Value))
```

Another way would be to get property with the recursive flag set to true like so:

```
var emailContact = Model.GetProperty("emailContact ", true).Value;
```

(See this post: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/19005-Recursive-fields-using-Razor-macro?p=1)

On a side not, it looks like you are currently working with Documents and not "content nodes", is this a back office control or a front end control?

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for getting back on this. I will try this out. Appreciated

Comment: This is a Front End control for email inquiries